# Calendar (GregorianCalendar) .complete() method not visible?

Tags: java, calendar

So I read through a few different threads but none of them seem to directly address how I fix my issue. I'm trying to create a `Calendar` (`Gregorian`) and then use the `.complete()` method so that in my classes using this (`Paycheck`) class I can find relative `dates` and create `new Calendar(s)` from those dates to determine wages payed and wages owed. However, it's telling me that `.complete()` `.computeTime()` and `.computeFields()` are all not visible.

From what I've read, this seems to be because they are protected methods and even though I `import the java.util` for them, I can't access them because that class is not in my package. How do I get this so that I can call the `.complete()` method?

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class Paycheck {
    //fields
    protected double grossAmount;
    protected Calendar paymentDate;
    protected Calendar payPeriodStart;

    public Paycheck(double grossAmount, int iYear, int iMonth, int iDay, int sYear, int sMonth, int sDay) {
        this.grossAmount = grossAmount;

        TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago");
        this.paymentDate = new GregorianCalendar(iYear, iMonth, iDay);
        this.paymentDate.setTimeZone(tz1);
        this.paymentDate.complete(); //says "method not visible"


        this.payPeriodStart = new GregorianCalendar(sYear, sMonth, sDay);
        this.payPeriodStart.setTimeZone(tz1);

    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to call an internal method. How do you even know it exists? It's not described in the javadoc. What are you *really* trying to accomplish here? What perceived problem do you believe you have if you don't call `complete()`? Forget the method exists, and do what you need done. `GregorianCalendar` will work correctly without it.

Comment: @Andreas As I commented a couple other places, I did this because the fact that the method existed (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_calendar.htm) made me think it was necessary to set all of the other fields as it checks to see if they are all set (which made me think that fields are not set automatically in the constructor. My apologies. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you reading that when the java has better descriptions, and are the *official* specification? See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: @Andreas Good question. I know of that page, just force of habit clicking on the first Google result haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650770/calendar-gregoriancalendar-complete-method-not-visible#comment66605119_39650901) you wrote:

> I don't care about the actual time, I just want it to give me the date so I can determine the dayofweek (important based on various state laws).

That is very easy to do, and don't need any call to internal methods.

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2016, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 22);
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
System.out.println("Day of week (1=Sun, ..., 7=Sat): " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

*Output*

```
Day of week (1=Sun, ..., 7=Sat): 5
```

Output is `5` because today is `Thu 9/22/2016`, and that's the date that was given.

Comment: per my comment on the other answer: "Okay... so maybe this is my fault for misinterpreting the method spec... So what you're saying is that giving it a date in the constructor sets all of the fields like dayofweek etc? I mean, that makes sense to me, but the fact that the complete() method explicitly says that it sets all unset fields made me thing that they weren't automatically computed. That's my fault if that's the case, I didn't think to test that."

Comment: @BrandonHunter Incorrect. It's entirely up to the internal implementation to decide when to "set all of the fields". It's actually *deferred* until needed, which means that calling `get()` will call `complete()` first, before extracting the requested field.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Most of my experience in programming thus far has been in C so I'm used to having to do all the leg work myself. So that's my fault. Thanks for the knowledge haha.

Answer (score 0):

Let's compare the typing effort:

```
this.paymentDate = new GregorianCalendar(iYear, iMonth, iDay);
this.paymentDate.complete(); // Why do you need to call this one?
```

vs the code having the same effect

```
this.paymentDate = new GregorianCalendar(iYear, iMonth, iDay, 0, 0, 0);
// constructor taking extra hours, minutes, seconds ----------^
```

So **why do you try the almost-impossible of calling a protected method**?

---

In some cases, very limited in number, one really needs to call a protected/private method and this may be possible. Exemplifying:

```
Class<GregorianCalendar> clazz=GregorianCalendar.class;
Method completeMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("complete");
 // this does the trick if it doesn't throw security exceptions
completeMethod.setAccessible(true);
completeMethod.invoke(this.paymentDate);
```

See the Javadoc for [AccesibleObject.setAccessible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject[],%20boolean)), `Method` being derived from `AccessibleObject`

Comment: I'm using this contstructor:
"GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)

This constructs a GregorianCalendar with the given date set in the default time zone with the default locale."

per https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_gregoriancalendar.htm

Comment: I don't care about the actual time, I just want it to give me the date so I can determine the dayofweek (important based on various state laws).

Comment: Also, I tried your example even though I'm not sure what you were getting at, but just in case I missed something. Didn't resolve the visibility issue.

Comment: `new GregorianCalendar(iYear, iMonth, iDay)` and `new GregorianCalendar(iYear, iMonth, iDay, 0, 0, 0)` is the same thing.

Comment: @BrandonHunter "Didn't resolve the visibility issue" of course it didn't solve the visibility issue, it only make it not necessary. Why do you need it?

Comment: @BrandonHunter If you want it to determine the dayofweek, what's preventing you from calling `get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`???

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi `complete()` is never necessary.

Comment: Okay... so maybe this is my fault for misinterpreting the method spec... So what you're saying is that giving it a date in the constructor  sets all of the fields like dayofweek etc? I mean, that makes sense to me, but the fact that the complete() method explicitly says that it sets all unset fields made me thing that they weren't automatically computed. That's my fault if that's the case, I didn't think to test that.

Comment: @BrandonHunter - the `complete` method is for internal use only. Deriving from `GregorianCalendar` for specific purposes is possible and, in such cases, the derived class **may** need to fill the rest of incomplete fields with defaults. In such cases and only such cases, `complete`provides convenience.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi The edit you posted is very helpful, though as you and Andreas cleared up, probably not necessary in this situation. Thanks for the help and my apologies for my overthinking ignorance haha.

Comment: @Andreas 'complete() is never necessary.' - really? Then I wonder why the author of `GregorianCalendar` provided one? Even more, a `protected` one, not even `private`? Perhaps there *is* a reason even if you can't think of it?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Sorry, let me clarify: `complete()` is never needed for *users* of `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar`. It may be needed for *implementors* of alternate calendar systems, but those people are few and far between.